# Python Numpy dtype change without changing source code

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm in trouble with python code.

Can I change numpy dtype without changing source code?
here the example,

`np.asarray([0,5,10,15], dtype=np.float32)/297`

here the float32 is not suitable for my calculation. So I want to change it to float64.
But I can't change python source code.
Can I do this without changing source code ?
Is there any python option for changing data type?

Thank You

Comment: `.astype('float64')`. See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Comment: Thanks, but i can't modify the source code....

Comment: what do you mean by *not changing the source code*? If you can't modify the code, then it's definitely `float32` for you.

Comment: Yes. I can't modify the code... But i want to find some way to change the data type by using python option or setting enviroment variable without changing source code.

Comment: How are you able to access the array? For example, you could just copy and paste the array from the source code to your own program and then modify it, but I am assuming this isn't what you want.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want, but it's the way I used to think. It's hard to find a better way than that. I will try. Thank you Tyson!